# Firefox Developer Edition allowing disabled select options to be chosen

Tags: jquery

I have a select in a jQuery dialog box that allows a user to move a "task" from one section to another.  There are only 4 options, and each "task" will be in one of those 4.  I am passing the current section number (1,2,3,4) to the modal, and disabling the current section that the task is in.

Here is the code that is doing that:

```
...
else if ($(this).val() === 'moveTask') {
    $("#selTaskType").find("option").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() === taskSectionNumber){
            $(this).prop('disabled',true);
        }
        else{
            $(this).prop('disabled',false);
        }
    });
    $("#moveTaskModal")
        .data("templateTaskId", templateTaskId)
        .data("sectionBasis",taskSectionNumber)
        .dialog("open");
    }
...
}
```

Here is the select in the modal.  Any of the 4 options can be disabled based on the current section of the task:

```
<select id="selTaskType">
    <option value="">Select a Section</option>
    <option disabled="" value="1">Performance Monitor</option>
    <option value="2">Predictive Maintenance</option>
    <option value="3">Preventive Maintenance</option>
    <option value="4">Preventive Replacement</option>
</select>
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2bo8hcfz/3) for it happening

I have checked that in Chrome (43.0.2357.81) and it works as expected, but in FF Dev Ed (40.0.a2), the disabled element remains lite, and allows the user to choose it.  Is anyone else seeing this, and if so, is it a known bug?  Are there any work arounds?

EDIT: I have asked a few co-workers, and they are seeing it working properly.  I It appears to only be happening to me. :\

Comment: I just tried it out and I am seeing the first selection properly disabled on Firefox Developer Edition 40.0a2 (2015-06-08).

Comment: Can confirm @SpacemanSpiff, tried it with the same build. Mozilla runs a bug-tracker at [bugzilla.mozilla.org](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/). StackOverflow is not the best place to discuss possible bugs.

Comment: @still_learning Would you consider it a bug if I'm the only one seeing it? No one else can even reproduce it.

Comment: I did not claim it is a bug, *you* asked whether this is a bug ;) anyway, I know it sucks to be unable to reproduce a problem... Good luck!

Comment: I have the same problem in my FF dev edition: 40.0a2 (2015-06-16). I am able to select all the options in your fiddle.

Comment: Well at least I'm not the only one!